# How to improve/simplify query with subqueries?

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I want to know the maximum formation level of people, and a person can have many formation entries.

Table **t_formation**

```
idFormation | fkPerson   | fkLevel     | place
------------------------------------------------
    1       |     1      |     2       | Oxford
    2       |     2      |     1       | PlaySchool
    3       |     1      |     3       | Trinity High
    4       |     1      |     1       | My School
    5       |     2      |     3       | My High
```

Table **a_level**

```
idLevel | orderLevel | formation
-------------------------------------
  1     |   1        |  School
  2     |   3        |  University
  3     |   2        |  High school
```

What I need to get is the following **query** or desired query result
(*the max order level with formation of each person and the place where they studied that max formation*)

```
fkPerson | maxOrderLevel |  formation    |  place
----------------------------------------------------
      1  |      2        |   Univertity  |  Oxford
      2  |      3        |   High school |  My High
```

To do that, I made a query with 2 subquerys but it was impossible to create a efficient view.

**Query SQL** without place, this get max formation of each person

```
select fkPerson, a_level.orderLevel, a_level.formation
from (
  select fkPerson,  max(a_level.orderlevel) as ordermax
  from t_formation left join a_level on t_formation.fkLevel = a_level.idLevel 
  group by fkPerson
) as form left join a_level on form.ordermax = a_level.orderlevel
```

Comment: why is `1 and 3` not included?

Comment: can you explain more about your problem??

Comment: *I made a query with 2 subquerys*. Then show the query first. Also explain your expected result. And please don't go away after putting a question.

Comment: There is not 3 fkPerson

Comment: please post the query or at least the desired output

Comment: the query is the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you can have multiple `orderLevel` values for each `fkPerson` so you will have to retrieve the `max(orderLevel)` for each `fkPerson` and then perform another join to get the `place`/`formation` that is associated with each person.

I see a couple ways that you can get the result.

You can use a subquery to get the `max(orderLevel)` and then join on your tables to return the desired columns:

```
select t1.fkPerson, 
  at.MaxOrder,
  t1.Place,
  a.Formation
from t_formation t1
inner join a_level a
  on t1.fkLevel = a.idLevel
inner join
(
  select t.fkPerson, max(a.orderLevel) MaxOrder
  from t_formation t
  left join a_level a
    on t.fkLevel  = a.idLevel
  group by t.fkPerson
) at
  on t1.fkPerson = at.fkPerson
  and at.maxorder = a.orderLevel;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/?r44b=no#!2/d4583/16).

The other way that you could get the result would be to use a query in your `WHERE` clause to filter the rows that do not have the `max(orderLevel)`:

```
select t.fkperson,
  a.orderlevel,
  t.place,
  a.formation
from t_formation t
left join a_level a
  on t.fkLevel = a.idLevel
where a.orderlevel = (select max(orderlevel)
                      from a_level a
                      inner join t_formation t1
                        on a.idlevel = t1.fklevel
                      where t.fkperson = t1.fkperson
                      group by t1.fkperson);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/?r44b=no#!2/d4583/17).

As a side note, your sample data does not seem to be able to give the result that you request.  The max `orderLevel` for `fkPerson = 2` is 3 not 2 so the formation will be `University` not `High School`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, last row or t_formatoin has to be like this
5       |     2      |     3       | My High

Comment: Which one would be the faster query or less heavy? I guess it would be the first one

Comment: I would go with the first suggestion. Possibly doing the subselect first and joining the other tables to it to more easily take advantage of the indexes when doing the join. The 2nd solution uses a correlated subquery and these can perform badly.

Comment: @Joe I would go with the first version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
SELECT fkPerson, fkLevel,orderLevel, formation, place
FROM t_formation as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_level as b ON a.fkLevel = b.idLevel
GROUP BY fkPerson HAVING orderLevel = max(orderLevel)
;
```

?

Comment: I don't get the expected result with this query as yours 
SELECT fkPerson, orderLevel as maxOrderLevel , formation, place
FROM t_formation as a 
LEFT outer JOIN a_level as b ON a.fkLevel = b.idLevel
GROUP BY fkPerson 
HAVING orderLevel = max(orderLevel)

I'm getting only one record instead of two :s